# Displaystring( ) not displaying on top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a countdown script that count down from a date that I set. Now I'm trying to separate the DAYS from the HOURS, MINUTES, and SECONDS. Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">



function cdLocalTime(container, servermode, offsetMinutes, targetdate, debugmode){
if (!document.getElementById || !document.getElementById(container)) return
this.container=document.getElementById(container)
var servertimestring=(servermode=="server-php")? '<? print date("F d, Y H:i:s", time())?>' : (servermode=="server-ssi")? '<!--#config timefmt="%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"--><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->' : '<%= Now() %>'
this.localtime=this.serverdate=new Date(servertimestring)
this.targetdate=new Date(targetdate)
this.debugmode=(typeof debugmode!="undefined")? 1 : 0
this.timesup=false
this.localtime.setTime(this.serverdate.getTime()+offsetMinutes*60*1000) //add user offset to server time
this.updateTime()
}

cdLocalTime.prototype.updateTime=function(){
var thisobj=this
this.localtime.setSeconds(this.localtime.getSeconds()+1)
setTimeout(function(){thisobj.updateTime()}, 1000) //update time every second
}

cdLocalTime.prototype.displaycountdown=function(baseunit, functionref){
this.baseunit=baseunit
this.formatresults=functionref
this.showresults()
}

cdLocalTime.prototype.showresults=function(){
var thisobj=this
var debugstring=(this.debugmode)? "<p style=\"background-color: #FCD6D6; color: black; padding: 5px\"><big>Debug Mode on!</big><br /><b>Current Local time:</b> "+this.localtime.toLocaleString()+"<br />Verify this is the correct current local time, in other words, time zone of count down date.<br /><br /><b>Target Time:</b> "+this.targetdate.toLocaleString()+"<br />Verify this is the date/time you wish to count down to (should be a future date).</p>" : ""

var timediff=(this.targetdate-this.localtime)/1000 //difference btw target date and current date, in seconds
if (timediff<0){ //if time is up
this.timesup=true
this.container.innerHTML=debugstring+this.formatresults()
return
}
var oneMinute=60 //minute unit in seconds
var oneHour=60*60 //hour unit in seconds
var oneDay=60*60*24 //day unit in seconds
var dayfield=Math.floor(timediff/oneDay)
var hourfield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay)/oneHour)
var minutefield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay-hourfield*oneHour)/oneMinute)
var secondfield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay-hourfield*oneHour-minutefield*oneMinute))
if (this.baseunit=="hours"){ //if base unit is hours, set "hourfield" to be topmost level
hourfield=dayfield*24+hourfield
dayfield="n/a"
}
else if (this.baseunit=="minutes"){ //if base unit is minutes, set "minutefield" to be topmost level
minutefield=dayfield*24*60+hourfield*60+minutefield
dayfield=hourfield="n/a"
}
else if (this.baseunit=="seconds"){ //if base unit is seconds, set "secondfield" to be topmost level
var secondfield=timediff
dayfield=hourfield=minutefield="n/a"
}
this.container.innerHTML=debugstring+this.formatresults(dayfield, hourfield, minutefield, secondfield)
setTimeout(function(){thisobj.showresults()}, 1000) //update results every second
}

/////CUSTOM FORMAT OUTPUT FUNCTIONS BELOW//////////////////////////////

//Create your own custom format function to pass into cdLocalTime.displaycountdown()
//Use arguments[0] to access "Days" left
//Use arguments[1] to access "Hours" left
//Use arguments[2] to access "Minutes" left
//Use arguments[3] to access "Seconds" left

//The values of these arguments may change depending on the "baseunit" parameter of cdLocalTime.displaycountdown()
//For example, if "baseunit" is set to "hours", arguments[0] becomes meaningless and contains "n/a"
//For example, if "baseunit" is set to "minutes", arguments[0] and arguments[1] become meaningless etc

//1) Display countdown using plain text
function formatresults(){
if (this.timesup==false){//if target date/time not yet met
var displaystring="<span style='background-color: #CFEAFE'>"+arguments[1]+" hours "+arguments[2]+" minutes "+arguments[3]+" seconds</span> left until launch time"
}
else{ //else if target date/time met
var displaystring="Launch time!"
}
return displaystring
}

//2) Display countdown with a stylish LCD look, and display an alert on target date/time
function formatresults2(){
if (this.timesup==false){ //if target date/time not yet met
var displaystring="<span class='lcdstyle'>"+arguments[1]+" <sup>hours</sup> "+arguments[2]+" <sup>minutes</sup> "+arguments[3]+" <sup>seconds</sup></span>"
}
else{ //else if target date/time met
var displaystring="" //Don't display any text
alert("Launch time!") //Instead, perform a custom alert
}
return displaystring
}

</script>
```

Now I've properly displayed the countdown, however, whenever I try to duplicate the countdown it doesn't display on the page. Here's the code I have so far:

```
             <div id="cdcontainer" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 80px; float: left; margin-

        top: 270px; margin-left: 50px;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        //cdLocalTime("cdcontainer", "server_mode", LocaltimeoffsetMinutes, "target_date", "opt_debug_mode")
        //cdLocalTime.displaycountdown("base_unit", formatfunction_reference)

        //Note: "launchdate" should be an arbitrary but unique variable for each instance of a countdown on your page:

        var launchdate=new cdLocalTime("cdcontainer", "server-php", 0, "December 21, 2013 19:10:00")
        launchdate.displaycountdown("days", formatresults2)

        </script>

    <div class="element" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: 170px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x170" /></div>
```

and here's a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish...

[image]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: does this look way more complicated than it should be??? it also has an author too... hmmmm, I don't even know if we should be messing with this

Comment: umm, you just removed the author with the copyright notice... not cool bro, not cool

Comment: I've read the terms of the author and he states that it's free to use. Also, he doesn't state that his name be in the script as a requirement for use. I just wanted to free everyone from confusion.